# How To Select Items Getting Expired Within A Specific Time In SQL Server?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, truncate

I am using SQL Server 2008 with a C# Windows Forms application. The products table has other values along with the expiry date and I want to show `ProductID, ProductName, AvailableQuantity, and ExpiryDate` in a grid so I can allow users to get an idea of items which are getting expired before the due date.

The purpose is to add only those products to that grid whose expiry date is getting closer, i.e. which are getting expired in 2 months.

I have tried using the `TRUNC` function like as follow:

```
select * 
from tblProducts 
where DateExpiry < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '62' DAY;
```

but I am getting the following error in SQL Server 2008:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Why I am getting this error? I have seen online that the same code is working fine, however, it is generating the error in my case. Is there any other way that can fulfill my requirements? Or do I have to modify the query somehow, which can help me resolve my error?

Comment: you are using a function from Oracle in Sql Server, try using date between, or date greater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server you should do this.

```
select * 
from tblProducts 
where DateExpiry < DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

DateDiff can be used to compute the total time frame between two dates. Those dates can come both from table values, or one can be "today's" date. I'd suggest you diff by total number of days rather than months because "a month" is a variable amount of time that changes often.

```
select * 
from tblProducts 
where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DateExpiry) < 62
```

It's assumed that `DateExpiry` *should* be greater than the current date, because we're looking for values that have not expired yet, but should soon.

Rather than trying to compute what "today plus 62 days" is, then trying to see if the database value is less than that, the command just subtracts the database value from the current date and checks if it's less than a number.

This selects anything that has will expire in less than 62 days from today.

More reading on [DateDiff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Your solution is working fine as well, but as per my requirements, I have to get products which are getting expired within 6 months. And for that reason, it seems difficult for me to accurately calculate months from days. This solution is best fit somewhere else in my application and I will be using it. Still, I am upvoting your solution for the time you spend in delivering that to me. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: @Noor you don't need to use the `day` argument, you can use `month` or [any of the other datepart arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments).